# Change all items of an array at once

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, postgresql

I wonder if there is a way of avoiding looping through all items of a list to access the same attribute.

```
people = [John, Bob, Dave, Eric]
```

with each have a number attribute (i.e. `John.num`)

so instead of `people.map{|person| person.num =10}`

I might do `people.[...some magic..].num = 10`

It just seems a waste to loop through all.. maybe with SQL or similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If people is an ActiveRecord model, you can use [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) method

```
Person.update_all("num=10")
```

Comment: the second arg to this method describes conditions how to select the records. This way: `Person.update_all("num=10", "age>20")`

Answer (score 0):

I case are a none AR Object, You can Monkey Patched Array but i think it's HORRIBLE way... I encourage you don't do that !!

```
class Person
  def num=(value)
    @num = value
  end
  def num
    @num
  end
end

class Array

  def num value = 10
    self.each do |element|
      element.__send__(:num=, 10) if element && element.respond_to?(:num)
    end
  end

end

begin
  john = Person.new
  bob  = Person.new
  [john, bob].num
  puts "john.num => #{john.num}"
end
```